# Combining product and chain rule in derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Can someone confirm whether the following derivative is correct?

I want to find the derivative with respect to S of:

$S*\exp((b-r)*T) * N(x_1) $ where $x_1 = \frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T)$

What I found:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial S} S*\exp((b-r)*T) * N(x_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial S} S*\exp((b-r)*T) * \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)} * \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$

Plugging in $x_1 = \frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T)$ yields

$\frac{\partial}{\partial S} S*\exp((b-r)*T) * \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)} * \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2})$

Now, using the productrule where

$f(S) =S*\exp((b-r)*T) * \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)}$

and

$g(S) = \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2}) $

we can find the derivative by $f'(S)g(S)+f(S)g'(S)$.

$f'(S) = \exp((b-r)*T) * \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)}$

$g'(S) = \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2}) * \frac{1}{S\sigma \sqrt(T)} $ (where I used the chainrule)

Thus, $\frac{\partial}{\partial S} = f'(S)g(S)+f(S)g'(S) = \exp((b-r)*T) * \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)} * \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2}) \\ +  S*\exp((b-r)*T) * \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)} * \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2}) * \frac{1}{S\sigma \sqrt(T)} $

Comment: Looks not correct. Due to the product rule, the $N(x_1)$ term cannot disappear completely. Recommendation : use python, generate random inputs and check such calculations at least numerically. Much more efficient than asking others to do that work.

Comment: Thanks @KurtG. I replace $N(x_1)$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)} * \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2})$, that is why I thought $N$ would dissapear.

Comment: It is incorrect to replace $N(x_1)$ by $N'(x_1)$ two times. Product rule requires $N(x_1)$ and $N'(x_1)$. To $N'(x_1)$ you apply the chain rule. That's it.

Comment: Thanks @KurtG. What I am saying, is that I completely replace $N(x_1)$ by the expression in my other comment (or in the post), thus why should there be a $N'(x_1)$ in the expression?

Comment: Your derivation already becomes incorrect where you define $g(x)$. This $g(x)$ should be $N(x)$. Then $f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$ . The chain rule you need on $g'(x)$ because $x$ is a function of $S$. BTW writing $f(x)=S\exp((b-r)T)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is appalling because there is no $x$ that is a function of $S$.

Comment: Thanks @KurtG., Appreciate it whenever you try to help. But now you are only making it more complicated and whenever I ask you something for the second time because you didn't read it correctly the first time, you downvote the question. Come on man, either help or don't say anything at all.

Comment: Why did you define $g(x)$ by $N'(x)$ and not by $N(x)$ ?

Comment: I define $g(S)$ by neither $N'(x)$ nor $N(x)$, I rewrite $N(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi)} * \exp(-\frac{(\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma \sqrt(T)} + (1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt(T))^2}{2})$. After that, I rewrite the equation into g(S) and f(S) in order to apply the product rule

Comment: Is $N(x)$ the CDF or the PDF of the standard normal distribution ?

Comment: $N(x_1)$ is the CDF

Comment: As I thougt. Then you cannot rewrite it the way you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the good old product rule to
$$
\underbrace{Se^{(b-r)T}}_{f(S)}\,\underbrace{N(x_1)}_{g(S)}\quad\text{ where }x_1=\frac{\ln(S/X)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}+(1+\mu)\sigma\sqrt{T}\,
$$
and $N(x)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. The derivative of $g$ w.r.t. $S$ will include the applcation of the chain rule to $N(x_1)$:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\Big\{Se^{(b-r)T}\,N(x_1)\Big\}=\underbrace{e^{(b-r)T}\color{red}{N(x_1)}}_{f'(S)\,g(S)}+\underbrace{Se^{(b-r)T}\,N'(x_1)\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial S}}_{f(S)\,g'(S)}\\
&=e^{(b-r)T}\color{red}{N(x_1)}+Se^{(b-r)T}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Bigg(-\frac{(\ln(S/X)+(1+\mu)\sigma^2T)^2}{2\sigma^2T}\Bigg)\frac{1}{S\sigma\sqrt{T}}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really useful! One more question, why is the last expression equal to $\exp(-\frac{(ln(S/X)+(1+\mu)\sigma^2T)^2}{2\sigma^2T})$ and not $\exp(-\frac{(ln(S/X)+(1+\mu)\sigma \sqrt{T})^2}{2})$? Those two equations are according to Python not the same

Comment: Express $x_1$ as $\frac{\ln(S/X)+(1+\mu)\sigma^2T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$ and put into $N'(x_1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x_1^2/2).$

Comment: Solved it, thanks a lot! Have a great day